# Trying to merge 2 files but ignore new lines

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to merge 2 lists together: Only copy over common differences, but ignore new lines. Might be easier to explain by this:

```
a.txt                 b.txt
abc                   123 
def                   abc.^$234,~12
ghi                   abcdd
jkl                   asdf
mnn                   ghi.^$321,~11
opq                   jkl
                      mnn^$qws
                      zxy
```

**Becomes:**

```
output.txt:
abc.^$234,~12
def
ghi.^$321,~11
jkl
mnn^$qws
opq
```

Trying to combine to lists, copy common lines while dropping new lines.

Comment: Trying to merge to lists together, dropping new lines. and combining existing

Comment: I don't understand the rules that determine what the output file looks like. What does "drop new lines" mean? New lines? Newlines/linebreaks? Which ones? Why is `abc` paired with the second line of `b.txt`, and not `123`, the first line?

Comment: `copy common lines` Why is `mnn^$qws` in the output?

Comment: Considering `abc.^$234,~12` and `abcdd` why is the first and not the second in the output?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '1{x;s/.*/cat file2/e;x};G;s/^([^\n]+)(\n.*)*\n(\1\>[^\n]*).*/\3/;P' file1
```

Slurp file2 into the hold space and then append it to each line in file1.

If the word in file1 matches a word in file2, print the contents of that line in file2. Otherwise, print the current line in file1.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the diff and patch commands, they might help you.

```
diff -u old_file new_file > change.diff
patch new_file < change.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$0]
    next
}
{
    for(i in a)
        if(index(i,$0)) {
            print i
            next
        }
    print
}' b a
```

Output:

```
abc.^$234,~12
def
ghi.^$321,~11
jkl
mnn^$qws
opq
```

Comment: Looking promising, seems to error if one of the lines has `|` , sorry for not checking for this in the testcase

Comment: Oh yeah, probably considers it a regex char. Could you add such a value pair to the sample files, please.

Comment: Replaced `i~$0` with `index(i,$0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're requirements aren't at all clear but this will produce the expected output you posted given the sample input you posted so it may be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -F'[^[:alnum:]]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $1)}' b.txt a.txt
abc.^$234,~12
def
ghi.^$321,~11
jkl
mnn^$qws
opq
```